# How do you remove a vertex from a polygon with multiple paths?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

In googlemaps api, when editing a polygon with multiple paths, removeAT eliminates the wrong vertex

For simple polygons, the removeAT will remove the correct vertex, but for multiple path polygons, it seems to remove only the vertex number from the first path.

Given this definition of a polygon for multiple paths:

```
var blockpolygon = newgoogle.maps.Polygon({
paths: [blockcoords0,blockcoords1,blockcoords2,blockcoords3,blockcoords4,blockcoords5]
});
```

where the paths are previously defined, for example:

```
var blockcoords4 = [{lat:51.799693211411,lng:-114.12380330669},{lat:51.799109509173,lng:-114.12273800578},{lat:51.799558197929,lng:-114.1223323167},{lat:51.799684004911,lng:-114.12232429316},{lat:51.799876802912,lng:-114.12248608283},{lat:51.800102904916,lng:-114.12290678386},{lat:51.800133809341,lng:-114.12306439938},{lat:51.800077007986,lng:-114.12331471639},{lat: 51.799693211411, lng: -114.12380330669}];
```

and the polygon is set as editable

When this event fires:

```
blockpolygon.addListener("rightclick", function(event)
{
this.getPath().removeAt(event.vertex);
}
```

The vertex from the first path on the list is removed, which is not the vertex that was "clicked"

Is there any way to remove the vertex from the correct path?

If I could identify which path and have the removeAT pointed to the correct path, that would make my day.

Comment: `this.getPath()` returns the first path.  Use `this.getPaths()` (with an 's'), to get all the paths.

Answer (score 0):

the hint from geocodezip was enough.  Here's the solution:

```
blockpolygon.addListener("rightclick", function(event)
    {
    for (i=0; i<this.getPaths().getLength(); i++)
        {
        for (j=0; j< this.getPaths().getAt(i).getLength(); j++)
            {
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(event.latLng, this.getPaths().getAt(i).getAt(j));
            if (distance==0) this.getPaths().getAt(i).removeAt(j);
            }
        }
}
```